# Cost of accessing vm

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vpn

I have created virtual machine on my azure account. Through Remote desktop protocol,I have accessing virtual machine. I want to calculate cost of doing virtual private network or private connection to access virtual machine?

Comment: you want the Pricing calculator?https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Price by checking the [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/). Add VPN from the services and pass the number of hours.